# PyMaps variable isn't found

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3

I'm poking at the PyMaps with the Google Maps API, and here is the sample code I found from
http://www.lonelycode.com/2008/12/04/google-maps-and-django/

```
def showmap():
from pymaps import Map, PyMap # import the libraries

# Create a map - pymaps allows multiple maps in an object
tmap = Map()
tmap.zoom = 3

# Latitude and lognitude - see the getcords function
# to see how we convert from traditional D/M/S to the DD type
# used by Googel Maps

lat = 0.0
long = 0.0

# These coordinates are for Hong Kong
dlat = "22 15 0 N"
dlong = "114 10 60 E"

dlat = dcode.lat.split(" ")
dlong = dcode.long.split(" ")

# Convert the coordinates
lat = getcords(float(dlat[0]), float(dlat[1]), float(dlat[2]), dlat[3])
long = getcords(float(dlong[0]), float(dlong[1]), float(dlong[2]), dlong[3])

# Inserts html into the hover effect
pointhtml = "Hello!"

# Add the point to the map
point = (lat, long, pointhtml, icon.id)

tmap.setpoint(point)
tmap.center = (1.757537,144.492188)

# Put your own googl ekey here
gmap = PyMap(key=GOOGLE_KEY, maplist=[tmap])
gmap.addicon(icon)

# pymapjs exports all the javascript required to build the map!
mapcode = gmap.pymapjs()

# Do what you want with it - pass it to the template or print it!
return mapcode
```

The problem is that I get an error when I run the program, I get "NameError: global name 'dcode' is not defined" Just what exactly is dcode and where do I find it? Is it a mistype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it should be something like this:

```
# These coordinates are for Hong Kong
dlat = "22 15 0 N"
dlong = "114 10 60 E"

dlat = dlat.split(" ")
dlong = dlong.split(" ")
```

You'll probably run into trouble here if you haven't imported the `getcords` function anywhere either.

```
# Convert the coordinates
lat = getcords(float(dlat[0]), float(dlat[1]), float(dlat[2]), dlat[3])
long = getcords(float(dlong[0]), float(dlong[1]), float(dlong[2]), dlong[3])
```

Also I'd recommend against using `long` as a variable name, since it's an `int` type.

```
In [98]: long?
Type:       type
String Form:<type 'long'>
Namespace:  Python builtin
```

Comment: Yeah, I cleaned up the code a bit as well, long is a horrible variable name. I just pasted the original. Thanks!